# Recover data from PERC 6/i RAID5 array using software RAID

Tags: software-raid, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, raid5, perc6

I have 4 hard drives from a RAID5 array from a Dell server that suffered physical damage to the PERC 6/i RAID controller card.

The 4 disks themselves are undamaged and I've created 4 disk images using ddrescue.

Is there a way in Debian to recover the RAID array from the 4 images to a new disk image without the use of a new PERC 6/i controller card? (i.e. recovering the RAID array in software cf hardware).

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Can't help with Debian I'm afraid, but there is software that can recover the data that was on the array. It won't create a brand new array, but it gives you a chance to get the data off the system and back it up.

The only one I've had success with was [Zero Assumption Recovery](http://www.z-a-recovery.com/raid-recovery.htm).

However, the easiest thing to do would be to get a new PERC 6/i card and just plug them in; it should re-detect the existing array and just re-mount it.

Comment: +1 - If the disks truly are "undamaged" just get a new RAID card and you should be OK.  If the disks AREN'T undamaged then you can consider other recovery options (as you already have images of them you have a lot of options).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I was hoping someone might know some voodoo with dd or similar to avoid the outlay on new hardware for data recovery.

Comment: I'm currently looking at Pyraid (http://code.google.com/p/pyraid) and raidextract (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/linux/raidextract).

Comment: if avoiding new hardware is the issue, then go find a local off lease or computer recycling company. You can easily get used PERC controller cards at very low prices.